# Terms and newsletter opt-in with SSO

Tags: registration, newsletter, terms-of-service, single-sign-on, email-verification

I have problems to combine a SSO (Single Sign On) registration flow with a required opt-in for newsletter/marketing.

The product I work for offers a service which requires a registration to get access. We offer e-mail/password and SSO (google, facebook) as optional ways to register. Users who have decided to sign up with e-mail are asked, whether they want to receive e-mails (marketing) or not … as we operate in e.g. Germany users have to opt-in actively by clicking a checkbox. Similar thing with terms/policy, but here we are allowed to frame it with a passive acceptance like a sentence "On sign-up you agree with our terms and […]" and the click on the sign-up button.

As we are implementing SSO now, I am looking for best practice examples and advice how to combine the terms and especially the active newsletter opt-in with a typical pop-up SSO registration flow. Here some additional thoughts:

- I could add another step post account creation, but the user has to accept terms together with account creation, because he has to accept the policy of using SSO before he uses SSO (obviously (-:)
- Same for newsletter, as I want to get the acceptance here as early as possible to be allowed to send e-mails to users who drop off in the following step
- Here one example I have found so far, but with a little bit weird interaction (try to sign-up with google): https://crello.com/de/signup/

Ideas appreciated (-:

Comment: what is meaning of SSO?

Comment: Single Sign On … the popular buttons like 'sign in with Google'